# How to suppress cypress headless chrome logs?

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, cypress

Cypress is being run in CircleCI inside a docker via command:
`command: npx cypress run --headless --browser chrome`

It prints too much info as well as Cypress tests results as:

`base_1  | 127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2021:19:52:18 +0000] "GET /roof.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 547 "http://`

I want to omit these requests logs.

Comment: Most commands can use option `{log: false}`. Hope this helps you

Comment: @RosenMihaylov But there are page transitions done w/o cypress commands. For example we click any button and applicaiton opens new page, there will be many requets logged, I suppose by chrome itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cypress-server#Arguments) Paste this in `cypress/support/index.js`

```
Cypress.Server.defaults({
  delay: 500,
  force404: false,
  whitelist: (xhr) => {
    // handle custom logic for whitelisting
    return true;
  }
})
```